# Kibana 4 - Why does my simple query return correct results when using .raw but not without?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, logstash, kibana-4

I'm trying out Elasticsearch/Kibana 4 and while my simple query:

```
program.raw:"MYAPPLICATION" AND entityId.raw:"12345-67N"
```

will return the results I want - i.e. result posts having the program and entityId field and containing the queried terms straight off, as I want.

However, I guess the right way to query this would be:

```
program:"MYAPPLICATION" AND entityId:"12345-67N"
```

but that gives my correct results only regarding the program query, and then a lot of hits on terms containing N or n. The entityId-part seems to only query on N?. I'm confused, please explain this. I've read up on the Lucene query syntax and can't find anything explaining this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .raw fields are setup by logstash as "not_analyzed" fields in elasticsearch.  As such, they are not split into tokens and can be used intact.

To elasticsearch, `entityId` really looks like ['12345', '67n'], which is why your query doesn't match.

Note that, in your example, program:myapplication should work (since there are no special characters).  Lowercase is automatic, IIRC.

Comment: I was suspecting this, but wanted to be hear someone else say it! Thanks Alain. I guess I would have to configure logstash or elasticsearch how to handle these fields like I want before it would work.

Comment: If you have fixed indexes, setup a mapping.  If you have dynamic (daily, etc) indexes, setup a template.  Good luck!